# In Sync framework application,the Sync process is not considering the Filter condition during the upload ( i.e from Remote to server db)

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, microsoft-sync-framework

i am deprovisioning the template whenever i am changing the filter condition.  when i synchronize the databases the data is correctly synchronized using the filter condition for the condition when i make some changes at the central db.

But when i make some changes at the remote db all the records are synchronized and uploaded to the server db irrespective of the Filter condition..

can anyone tell what i am missing.

if you guys are not clear i can also show you some code. tell me which function or what more should i tell you.

Comment: [How to: Filter Rows and Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726003.aspx): "There is no mechanism to prevent an application from inserting data at the client that is outside of that client's partition. You could add constraints at the client to disallow out-of-partition inserts and updates."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you provisioning the clients? If your using Get Description of scope from the server scope, the scope definition it returns doesn't include filters.

Comment: JuneT thanks for replying so fast. I already solved the filter problem.  But i am stuck with a new issue. when ever i am updating filter condition for the table.i deprovision the previous scope and create a new template. due to which the tracking tables are getting deleted and now when i sync the db a conflict remote insert and local insert comes and the changes done at the client are lost if i am using server win and server changes are lost if using client win. Can you tell me a way to deal with this problem so i dont have to delete the scopes or the tracking table.?